# Web service not sending the data on second time if i make a request to webserver

Tags: asp.net, web-services

Web service not sending the data on second time if i make a request to webserver.

```
[WebMethod]
public DataSet SeePatientNotes(string strUserID, string secureHash2, string strDeviceDetails, string appId, string patID)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dtPatientInfo = new DataTable();
    try
    {
            code.....Adding dtPatientInfo to ds
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        clsLogging.LogException(ex, "SeePatientNotes");
    }
    finally
    {
        dtPatientInfo.Dispose();
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: What makes you say that? Are you sure that the second request is actually reaching the server? Did you log every request with that `clsLogging`

Comment: yes, I log every request but by making a second request from an android device not receiving data.